# Three way circuit powering a GFCI outlet

Tags: electrical

I have two light switches, one at each entry to a room, that are set up three way to power a standard outlet (for a lamp).  I replaced that standard outlet with a GFCI outlet.  I noticed that the tiny, green GFCI status light goes out when the switches are in the off position and that if the switches are in the off position, the GFCI outlet will not RESET after testing.  This all seems logical to me but it got me wondering if there anything wrong with using a GFCI outlet like this?

Comment: What sort of room are we talking about here?

Comment: Why do you want to use a GFCI?

Comment: The indicator light may be the problem, I would not be putting GFCI protection on a lighting circuit but there is nothing wrong with that. Down vote removed, Some circuits like garages with plug in lights do require GFCI protection so it may even be required.

Answer (score 2):

You can switch a GFCI outlet like you describe. Obviously the green LED indicator is powered from the power coming to the outlet so it stands tor reason that it would go off when the power to the outlet is switched off.

It is possible that some loads that you plug into an outlet like this could cause nuisance tripping of the GFCI when the switch is turned on and off quickly. This would only be likely to happen with devices that do not have properly balanced front end AC EMI filters that are tied into the safety ground.

Answer (score 0):

While this *should* be OK, you may want to rewire things so that the GFCI is either in the panel (protecting everything on the circuit) or somewhere between the panel and the switch. That would allow the GFCI to stay on all the time.

This could be done with a breaker in the panel or replacing a receptacle earlier in the circuit with a GFCI (you could swap the new GFCI/receptacle with the other receptacle), or adding a new GFCI/receptacle or "deadfront" GFCI somewhere in the circuit. The key, of course, is to make sure that the wires going to the switch are powered from the **load** side of a GFCI.